# Detect when just text is selected using textViewDidChangeSelection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, selection

I've currently been using `textViewDidChangeSelection` to detect when the user has selected some text. A problem I've been facing is that when the user moves the carot, it still sends that message to the delegate. So then I try to grab the user's selected text and get errors from my other methods because the string is empty. I'm using the `selectedTextRange` property of course. So then I tried putting an if statement in the `textViewDidChangeSelection` saying

```
//Selected text is the selected text created in the method 
//textViewDidChangeSelection.

if (selectedText.length > 0) {
//Do stuff
}
```

This works fine except that when the user backspaces, the if statement is passed because for some reason the "selectedText" is the character that gets deleted therefore `length>0`. I've tried various other things like detecting if it was a backspace that was just pressed, etc. but nothing seems to work. So how can I get the selected text when actual text is selected? I also need to know when actual text is selected so I can move some UI elements around but not every backspace because that would just be annoying.

Comment: What is `selectedRange` property when this method is called for `Backspace`?

Comment: @sha for some reason the method is called twice when I backspace but the first time its called, the length is 1, the second time, the length is 0.

Comment: Again, please check `selectedRange` and not only length but a position as well.